# How does an SSL-enabled Cloudflare proxy connect to a non-SSL endpoint?

Tags: ssl, proxy, cloudflare

new Cloudflare user here.

I have an A record, but I don't have the any cert installed on the server that I'm pointing to. I know you can proxy through CF and CF has free SSL set up on the proxy endpoint.

My question is: how does CF connect to my endpoint securely? Or am I understanding incorrectly?

My understanding:

me --[SSL-enabled]--> CF Proxy --[no SSL?]--> my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that CloudFlare **doesn't** connect to your endpoint securely through their free SSL certificate.

CloudFlare offers three types of SSL setups, with '**flexible**' being the default:

> **Flexible**: They'll serve content over HTTPS from their infrastructure, but the connection between them and the origin is unencrypted
>
> **Full**: Still HTTPS from CloudFlare to the browser but they'll also talk HTTPS to the origin although they won't validate the certificate
>
> **Full (strict)**: CloudFlare issues the certificate and they'll intercept your traffic, but then it's all HTTPS to the origin and the cert is validated as well

While a flexible, free SSL certificate from CloudFlare will show your visitors a secure HTTPS padlock, this **[method of SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/)** only exists between CloudFlare and the ISP, **not** between CloudFlare and your server. The flexible certificate is shared between 50 different domains (revealing each of these to your visitors), though does indeed protect from common attacks such as WiFi snooping.

---

### Flexible:

[image: Flexible]

---

### Full:

[image: Full]

---

A **Full** certificate also encrypts traffic between CloudFlare and the origin, *but CloudFlare doesn't validate the cert*. A **strict** certificate remedies this.

If unsure on the quality of your SSL, I'd recommend checking out **[Qualys' SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest)**.

For more information see **[Troy Hunt's article](https://www.troyhunt.com/cloudflare-ssl-and-unhealthy-security-absolutism/)** on the issue.

Comment: *"... CloudFlare doesn't connect to your endpoint securely through their free SSL certificate."* - full ssl is also offered with free certificates in which case the connection between Cloudflare and the origin is secured too. Cloudflare does not provide any kind of end-to-end (client to origin) encryption though because otherwise it could not provide the services as a CDN.

Comment: *"If unsure on the quality of your SSL, I'd recommend checking out Qualys' SSL Labs test."* - this will provide only information about the connection to CloudFlare. It will provide no information about the security of the connection between CloudFlare and the origin.

Answer (score 1):

> how does CF connect to my endpoint securely?

Since you don't offer a secure connection to your endpoint Cloudflare cannot use a secure connection to your endpoint. This is, only the connection between the browser and Cloudflare is secure but not the final connection from Cloudflare to your server.

See also the description of the [Flexible SSL option](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-) you are talking about which explicitly points of the problems:

> Flexible SSL: A Secure connection between your visitor and Cloudflare, but no secure connection between Cloudflare and your web server. ... This option is **not recommended if you have any sensitive information** on your website. ...It should only be used as a **last resort** if you are not able to setup SSL on your own web server. ...